# set softkeys on qt for symbian

Tags: qt, symbian

On E63 or similar smart phones,there can be three softkeys(the left and right one always named "OK"  or "Cancel" and the middle one always named "Select" or 'Query" alike actions' name) on the screen.QAction has this method:

```
void    setSoftKeyRole ( SoftKeyRole softKeyRole )
```

,and `SoftKeyRole` goes these descriptions:

```
QAction::NoSoftKey  0   This action should not be used as a softkey
QAction::PositiveSoftKey    1   This action is used to describe a softkey with a positive or non-destructive role such as Ok, Select, or Options.
QAction::NegativeSoftKey    2   This action is used to describe a softkey with a negative or destructive role role such as Cancel, Discard, or Close.
QAction::SelectSoftKey  3   This action is used to describe a role that selects a particular item or widget in the application.
```

I have used `PositiveSoftKeys` and `NegativeSoftKey` to set the left and right softkey,but I can never do `SelectSoftKey` to the middle one?I found nothing related to this on qt bug repository.What I want to do is make full use of the three softkeys on most smartphones.Can anybody figure out what happened?Thanks always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E63 does not have a touch screen,and it seems only smart phones with a touch screen(Nokia series) can set SelectSoftKey to the middle one.